# "Chamber of Secrets" and "Goblet of Fire" Tom Riddle connection?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

In *The Chamber of Secrets* we learn Tom Riddle is Lord Voldemort but in *The Goblet of Fire* when it talks about the people who lived in the Riddle House the older couple's son is named Tom Riddle. Are they the same person because it does say they "die" but are technically alive but is the name just supposed to be an Easter egg or some kind of add-on to Voldemort's origin?

Comment: The below answer is correct. Your question suggests that you have not yet the sixth book yet, where you will find out a lot about the backstory of the Riddle family. I suggest you finish reading the entire series before asking more questions that will be answered later.

Answer (score 18):

The Tom in the first chapter of Goblet of fire is Voldemort's father.

Tom Riddle senior is a muggle who was living in Little Hangleton with his parents. Merope Gaunt (Voldemort's mother) was enamored with Tom senior so she uses a love potion on Tom senior and they have a wedding and get pregnant.

When Merope was pregnant she stopped giving Tom Senior the potion so he abandoned Merope and returned to his parents.

When Voldemort (whose real name is Tom Marvolo Riddle like his father and maternal grandfather) returned to Little Hangleton he killed his own father and paternal grandparents; this is the couple and son that is mentioned in the first chapter of Goblet of Fire.